# Cloud-init nocloud set hostname dynamically from dhcp

Tags: networking, cloud-init

My initial idea is not to disable cloud-init from the ubuntu server 18.04.1 I'm configuring, but I think it will be what I  will do if I cannot solve this.

The issue is I'm setting the hostname dynamically from my DHCP server. However although I get systemd-hostname saying the new hostname is set, this is not true as in every reboot it is set back to the former.

I have try to modify the default cloud-init seed to remove the hostname line, but it is the same. Any idea?

```
# cloud-init clean
# modify user-data removing hostname
# cloud-init init
# reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to set `/etc/hostname` to `localhost` in order for the DHCP hostname to be considered. See `context_update_kernel_hostname()` in hostnamed (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/hostname/hostnamed.c#L267).

If you've already removed any `hostname` lines from `/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud[-net]/user-data` then cloud-init shouldn't be messing with the hostname anymore. Make sure you also run `sudo cloud-init clean` to remove any cached data from cloud-init.