# Does Ubuntu 18.04 use dhclient?

Tags: dhcp, netplan, dhclient, cloud-init, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to figure out how to configure my DHCP client on Ubuntu server 18.04.

I have the following netplan configuration, coming from cloud-init:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 02:dc:01:00:38:4c
            set-name: ens160
```

This seems to properly configure my network interface with an ip address, dns, default gateway and search domain. However, I'm wondering how to obtain a hostname from DHCP. I've been looking into dhclient which provides some convenient hooks that I can use, however it doesn't appear that dhclient hooks are being called. I've noticed that cloud-init calls dhclient as per the logs, but as some sort of sandboxed version, which seems to ignore the hooks.

I've also noticed that systemd-networkd reports some DHCP activity regarding to DHCP leases.

Could someone shed some light into the process?

Comment: Our DHCP server was expecting a particular MAC address : `dhcp-identifier: mac` at the same level than `dhcp4`solved my problem. Might not be yours but it might help others.

Answer (score 6):

I did more digging on this, so leaving some info for others.

Looks like Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't use dhclient anymore, which was called in daemon mode by `ifupdown`. Instead, `systemd-networkd` takes care of all things DHCP. In order to create DHCP client hooks, we must now use `systemd` (You can see an example of how this is done by looking at `ntp`'s files: `/lib/systemd/system/ntp-systemd-netif.{path|service}`).

As mentioned in the question, cloud-init does call dhclient in a sandboxed more, but only for some particular clouds.

In terms of setting the hostname, there may be conflicts between `systemd-networkd` and `cloud-init`. See [Cloud-init nocloud set hostname dynamically from dhcp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063911/cloud-init-nocloud-set-hostname-dynamically-from-dhcp/1072880#1072880).